# Kivy: Code Popup Dismiss Button in KV Language

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, kivy

I'm trying to code a custom popup in kivy for picking a color from the ColorPicker widget.  Right now i'm trying to hook up an 'OK' button to dismiss the popup, but it's not working.  The popup up displays correctly, but when i click OK, nothing happens.  The popup continues on screen.

Here's my python code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.colorpicker import ColorPicker

class PaintWindow(BoxLayout):
    pass

class CPopup(Popup):
    def on_press_dismiss(self, *args):
        self.dismiss()
        return False

class PixPaint(App):
    def build(self):
        pw = PaintWindow()
        return pw

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PixPaint().run()
```

Here's the KV code.

```
<PaintWindow>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    CPopup:

<CPopup>:
    title: 'Pick a Color'
    size_hint: 1.0, 0.6
    id: cpopup

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        ColorPicker:
            size_hint: 1.0, 1.0

        Button:
            text: 'OK'
            size_hint: 1.0, 0.2
            on_press: cpopup.on_press_dismiss()
```

Any help is much appreciated.  Sorry for all the code! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the popup is not closing is because you are adding it directly to your `PaintWindow` here:

```
<PaintWindow>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    CPopup:
```

Instead of actually calling the method `open()` of Popup. So,

1 - Remove the `CPopup:` from the kv file

```
<PaintWindow>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    #CPopup:
 ...
```

2 - Call the `open()` method somewhere else. As a good example in the `build(self)` of `PixPaint`

```
class PixPaint(App):
    def build(self):
        pw = PaintWindow()
        popup = CPopup();
        popup.open()
        return pw
```

Just in case, a few extras:

1. You can also get rid off the `id: cpopup` on the the definition of `<CPopup>:` and use `root` instead (`on_press: root.on_press_dismiss()`).
2. Moreover, you can get rid off the `on_press_dismiss()` and do `on_press: root.dismiss()` instead.

Comment: That makes sense.  The window was treating it as a permanent widget.  Thanks!